# Date increment from expression

Tags: bash, shell

Given this expression:

```
#!/bin/bash

date=20210825
partitions=3

for i in $(seq 0 $partitions); do

    start_time=$(date -d "${date} + ${i}*24/$partitions hour" +%H)"000"
    stop_time=$(date -d "${date} + $((i + 1))*24/$partitions hour" +%H)"000"
    echo $start_time
    echo $stop_time
done
```

I'm trying to evaluate the date increments based on the number of partitions, with the end-goal being N pairs of start_time and stop_time, where N=partitions. It keeps complaining about the syntax of the expressions for start_time and stop_time. Doing a simple increment with the iterator j works, but any arithmetic on it is not working currently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running your code shows:

> date: invalid date ‘20210825 + 0*24/3 hour’

Thats because the calculation should be inside the `$(())` syntax.

---

Change the code to:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

date=20210825
partitions=3

for i in $(seq 0 $partitions); do

    start_time=$(date -d "$((date + ($i * 24 / $partitions))) hour" +%H)"000"
    stop_time=$(date  -d "$((date + (($i + 1) * 24 / $partitions))) hour" +%H)"000"
    
    echo $start_time
    echo $stop_time
done
```

You might need to change to order of those `()` to get the desired output. Currently it shows:

```
04000
12000
12000
20000
20000
04000
04000
12000
```

Which you can test [in this online demo](https://tio.run/##lc5LCsIwEAbg/ZziN0ZILNI0KgjSvbeQ1kaahUlt4vljq4VSd85imAd8M3UV2pTWq7y2Lq@Hhqipoim10oU66SN1VR9ttN6Fck909z0srAMXwTyhwOe9PKPxRBgixGF6jfZhSi5GD7sGjItvnUFwiy30AfkCkBKtf/UM2eYimVKKTZrvFtivNnIZCvmH@Unm1nrw@dnFcLpJjXcmpTc).